# Error on build app iOS, only on the production URL (https) : TrustFailure (One or more errors occurred.)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a problem when building my iOS project, only on the URL production(for communication to web service). I think the problem is the protocol HTTPS but I don't find any solution for this.

My output:

P.S.: My HttpClient Implementation in iOS Build, is configured Managed(default)

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #10
The thread 0xa has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #11
The thread 0xb has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #6
The thread 0x6 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
2018-03-28 04:34:13.362 AppNivel.iOS[4830:44384] 
Unhandled Exception:
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: TrustFailure (One or more errors occurred.) ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> Mono.Security.Interface.TlsException: CertificateUnknown
  at Mono.AppleTls.AppleTlsContext.EvaluateTrust () [0x000ca] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.8.0.20/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/Mono.AppleTls/AppleTlsContext.cs:269 
  at Mono.AppleTls.AppleTlsContext.RequirePeerTrust () [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.8.0.20/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/Mono.AppleTls/AppleTlsContext.cs:210 
  at Mono.AppleTls.AppleTlsContext.ProcessHandshake () [0x00046] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.8.0.20/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System/Mon
o.AppleTls/AppleTlsContext.cs:186 
  at ...
  
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.8.0.20/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
  at AppNivel.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in D:\AppNivel_Bkp_14032018_1450h\AppNivel\AppNivel.iOS\Main.cs:17 
2018-03-28 04:34:13.366 AppNivel.iOS[4830:44384] Unhandled managed exception:
An error occurred while sending the request (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException)
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__64.MoveNext () [0x0046c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.8.0.20/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:406 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.8.0.20/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/msco
rlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.8.0.20/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at ...
2018-03-28 04:34:13.401 AppNivel.iOS[4830:44384] critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
The app has been terminated.
```

Comment: Can you connect to another third party https website? Let's get rid of the problem of your own web service.

Comment: I didn't tryed this, but my web service always worked in production url. Any ideas ?